# Unable to overwrite default value of "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" with Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to overwrite the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` parameter directly within the code:

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("SPARK")
  .getOrCreate()

sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 2)
```

But this setting does not take effect since in the logs I get the following warning message:

```
WARN  OffsetSeqMetadata:66 - Updating the value of conf 'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions' in current session from '2' to '200'.
```

While the same parameter passed in a `spark-submit` shell works:

```
#!/bin/bash

/app/spark-2/bin/spark-submit \
--queue root.dev \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 5G \
--executor-memory 4G \
--executor-cores 2 \
--num-executors 4 \
--conf spark.app.name=SPARK \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 \
--conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2 \
--class com.dev.MainClass
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

In the checkpoint files of your Spark Structured Streaming job, some of the `sparkSession` configurations are stored.

For example, in the folder "offset" the content for the latest batch could look like:

```
v1
{"batchWatermarkMs":0,"batchTimestampMs":1619782960476,"conf":{"spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass":"org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider","spark.sql.streaming.join.stateFormatVersion":"2","spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.compression.codec":"lz4","spark.sql.streaming.flatMapGroupsWithState.stateFormatVersion":"2","spark.sql.streaming.multipleWatermarkPolicy":"min","spark.sql.streaming.aggregation.stateFormatVersion":"2","spark.sql.shuffle.partitions":"200"}}
4
```

Among others, it stores the value of the configuration `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, which in my example is set to the default value of 200.

In the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/OffsetSeq.scala#L143) you will see, that this configuration value gets replaced in case it is available in the metadata of your checkpoint files.

In case you really have to change the partitions either remove all your checkpoint files or change the value manually to 2 in the last checkpoint files.

Comment: Thank you for these explanations.
If I want to change the value manually, do I need to modify it only in the latest file contained into the "offset" folder ?

Comment: I consider this to be very not user-friendly, to the point that I it's almost buggy. How can changing a spark setting without error still result in the setting not being changed? Very confusing.